# Correct setup of kops permissions for AWS k8s

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, kubernetes, kops

I [installed Kubernetes on AWS using kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md).  Part of this was setting up an IAM group and user:

```
aws iam create-group --group-name kops

aws iam attach-group-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess --group-name kops
aws iam attach-group-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonRoute53FullAccess --group-name kops
aws iam attach-group-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess --group-name kops
aws iam attach-group-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMFullAccess --group-name kops
aws iam attach-group-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonVPCFullAccess --group-name kops

aws iam create-user --user-name kops
aws iam add-user-to-group --user-name kops --group-name kops
aws iam create-access-key --user-name kops
```

My kubernetes is up, but every now and again I run into weird errors and failures (Like not being able to mount an EC2 EBS to a pod).  Thoughts are that perhaps its a permission thing.  So I go to IAM and see this:

[image]

The kops user and group have never accessed anything!

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be normal.

The problem was the [machine type of my workers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49684807/3421652).

My fully working cluster shows the same behavior.